# Search for a object list for a object with a minimum value and add that object with new value to a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

I have a class like this

```
         class car   
           {
             public string carName { get; set; }
             public decimal price { get; set; }//Group id
           }

         I have two lists like this

         List<car> listCars = new List<car>();
         List<car> lowest = new List<car>();
```

I want to search for the car with lowest price in the listCars list and add the lowest price car object to the list lowest.

```
      var minPrice = lstCars.Min(carobj=>carobj.price);
```

but in this you get only the minimum car price only. I want to get the car object and add it to the **lowest** list.
How to do that?

Comment: price is of type `string`. Is that a typo ?

Comment: @Habib yeah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your cars based on `Price` in ascending order, then get the first car which has the lowest price:

```
lowest.Add(listCars.OrderBy(car => car.price).First());
```

You can also use [`MinBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method, it would be more efficient for bigger lists because ordering is expensive.

Comment: thanks for the advice about changing the data type. I changed and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways of doing it. You can use `OrderBy` and then select `First` or you can use your already deteremined `minPrice` like:

```
var minPrice = lstCars.Min(carobj=>carobj.price);
lowest.Add(listCars.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.price == minPrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowest price which is `string`? Is this a price, then i would use `decimal`. If you also want to add all cars with the lowest price:

```
var minPriceGroup = listCars
    .Select(c => new { Car = c, Price = decimal.Parse(c.price) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Price)
    .First();
lowest.AddRange(minPriceGroup.Select(x => x.Car));
```